# Is there a way to replace rows in one dataframe with another in R?

Tags: r

I'm trying to figure out how to replace rows in one dataframe with another by matching the values of one of the columns. Both dataframes have the same column names.

Ex:

```
df1 <- data.frame(x = c(1,2,3,4), y = c("a", "b", "c", "d"))

df2 <- data.frame(x = c(1,2), y = c("f", "g"))
```

Is there a way to replace the rows of df1 with the same row in df2 where they share the same x variable? It would look like this.

```
data.frame(x = c(1,2,3,4), y = c("f","g","c","d")
```

I've been working on this for a while and this is the closest I've gotten -

```
df1[which(df1$x %in% df2$x),]$y <- df2[which(df1$x %in% df2$x),]$y
```

But it just replaces the values with NA.

Does anyone know how to do this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think what you need here is a "merge" or "join" operation.

(I add `stringsAsFactors=FALSE` to the frames so that the merging and later work is without any issue, as `factor`s can be disruptive sometimes.)

Base R:

```r
df1 <- data.frame(x = c(1,2,3,4), y = c("a", "b", "c", "d"), stringsAsFactors = FALSE)
# df2 <- data.frame(x = c(1,2), y = c("f", "g"), stringsAsFactors = FALSE)
merge(df1, df2, by = "x", all = TRUE)
#   x y.x  y.y
# 1 1   a    f
# 2 2   b    g
# 3 3   c <NA>
# 4 4   d <NA>
transform(merge(df1, df2, by = "x", all = TRUE), y = ifelse(is.na(y.y), y.x, y.y))
#   x y.x  y.y y
# 1 1   a    f f
# 2 2   b    g g
# 3 3   c <NA> c
# 4 4   d <NA> d
transform(merge(df1, df2, by = "x", all = TRUE), y = ifelse(is.na(y.y), y.x, y.y), y.x = NULL, y.y = NULL)
#   x y
# 1 1 f
# 2 2 g
# 3 3 c
# 4 4 d
```

Dplyr:

```r
library(dplyr)
full_join(df1, df2, by = "x") %>%
  mutate(y = coalesce(y.y, y.x)) %>%
  select(-y.x, -y.y)
#   x y
# 1 1 f
# 2 2 g
# 3 3 c
# 4 4 d
```

Comment: Thank you so much! The Dpylr version worked perfectly, and was elegent, too. The stringsAsFactors=FALSE was something I had never seen before, and I see now how helpful it is. :)

Answer (score 3):

We can use `match`.  :

```
inds <- match(df1$x, df2$x)
df1$y[!is.na(inds)] <- df2$y[na.omit(inds)]
df1

#  x y
#1 1 f
#2 2 g
#3 3 c
#4 4 d
```

Answer (score 3):

First off, well done in producing a nice reproducible example that's directly copy-pastable. That always helps, specially with an example of expected output. Nice one!

You have several options, but lets look at why your solution doesn't quite work:

First of all, I tried copy-pasting your last line into a new session and got the dreaded factor-error:

```
Warning message:
In `[<-.factor`(`*tmp*`, iseq, value = 1:2) :
  invalid factor level, NA generated
```

If we look at your data frames `df1` and `df2` with the `str` function, you will see that they do not contain text but *factors*. These are not text - in short they represent categorical data (male vs. female, scores A, B, C, D, and F, etc.) and are really integers that have a text as label. So that could be your issue.

Running your code gives a warning because you are trying to import new factors (labels) into `df1` that don't exist. And R doesn't know what to do with them, so it just inserts `NA`-values.

As r2evens answered, he used the `stringsAsFactors` to disable using strings as Factors - you can even go as far as disabling it on a session-wide basis using `options(stringsAsFactors=FALSE)` (and I've heard it will be disabled as default in forthcoming R4.0 - yay!).

After disabling `stringsAsFactors`, your code works - or does it? Try this on for size:

```
df2 <- df2[c(2,1),]
df1[which(df1$x %in% df2$x),]$y <- df2[which(df1$x %in% df2$x),]$y
```

What's in `df1` now? Not quite right anymore.

In the first line, I swapped the two rows in `df2` and lo and behold, the replaced values in `df1` were swapped. Why is that?

Let's deconstruct your statement `df2[which(df1$x %in% df2$x),]$y`

Call `df1$x %in% df2$x` returns a logical vector (boolean) of which elements in `df1$x` are found ind `df2` - i.e. the first two and *not* the second two. But it doesn't relate which positions in the first vector corresponds to which in the second.

Calling `which(df1$x %in% df2$x)` then reduces the logical vector to which indices were `TRUE`. Again, we do not now which elements correspond to which.

For solutions, I would recommend r2evans, as it doesn't rely on extra packages (although `data.table` or `dplyr` are two powerful packages to get to know).

In his solution, he uses `merge` to perform a "full join" which matches rows based on the value, rather than - well, what you did. With `transform`, he assigns new variables *within* the context of the data.frame returned from the `merge` function called in the first argument.

Comment: Wow, thank you so much for the context! I really appreciate you writing all that out. That all makes a lot of sense - I had never even considered factors before! I'm glad R4.0 will make that a default :) Thanks also for the context about the issues with which() and %in% - I'll take note of that in the future. I followed r2evans solution and it worked perfectly. :) thank you so much!

Answer (score 2):

A join option with `data.table` where we join `on` the 'x' column, assign the values of 'y' in second dataset (`i.y`) to the first one with `:=`

```
library(data.table)
setDT(df1)[df2, y := i.y, on = .(x)]
```

NOTE: It is better to use `stringsAsFactors = FALSE` (in `R 4.0.0` - it is by default though) or else we need to have all the `levels` common in both datasets